# jQuery & Bootstrap doesn't load after loading in AlpineJS

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-5, alpine.js

Before I loaded AlpineJS in, my bootstrap, livewire and jQuery was working fine.

After I added in the code to load AlpineJS as well, the browser keeps throwing Uncaught TypeErrors.
[image: jQuery, $ and Livewire not defined]

The code is as below. If I comment out the AlpineJS code portion, Livewire, jQuery and Bootstrap loads in fine. But once I uncomment the AlpineJS code, it will not load in.

[image: Excerpt of Code]

Moving the import bootstrap script to different lines to see if this could be due to a race condition, but to no avail. The issue is still present.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that AlpineJS is conflicting with either jQuery or Livewire, or there may be some other issue with your code. Here are a few steps you can try to troubleshoot the issue:

1. Make sure you have loaded AlpineJS after jQuery and Livewire in your HTML file.
2. Check for any JavaScript errors in the browser console. If you see any error messages, try to identify the source of the error and address it.
3. Try removing the AlpineJS code and see if jQuery and Livewire work properly without it. If they do, try adding the AlpineJS code back in one line at a time to see if a particular line of code is causing the issue.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).